# UK Standard Visitor Visa: How to mail multiple applications when applying as a family

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am a permanent resident of USA. I am making a trip to India but planning a stop-over in London,UK for a week.
For this stop-over , I am applying for a standard visitor visa. My biometric appointment has already been completed.
Now I have to send applications for the visa for both me and my wife.

1.) Should I send both applications in same envelope? Maybe, put each application in small envelope and then put both applications in a bigger envelope?

2.) Should I put my financial documents (Bank statements , Pay Slips) in both applications(i.e. mine and my wife's)?

3.) I have an old passport which is expired. Is there any need to send this passport as well with my application?

Thanks!

Comment: Please identify the British mission you are applying to along with your nationality.

Comment: New York. I am an Indian citizen.

Comment: You can ask if there's anything special to be aware of when Indian nationals use the VFS to submit their applications. If you have not already submitted.

Comment: I have already submitted. I have talked to their paid service and proceeded as per their advice. Once my application is processed, I have a few things to share.

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

**Should I send both applications in same envelope? Maybe, put each application in small envelope and then put both applications in a bigger envelope?**

This is a great question.  The best strategy is to treat both applications at 'arms length' when you send them.  The reason for this is that the mail room procedures for witnessing and logging evidence is done for one applicant at a time.

*Should I put my financial documents (Bank statements , Pay Slips) in both applications(i.e. mine and my wife's)?*

Another great question. Both applications should have the spouse's GWF number written large and plainly visible in the remarks section. Include the financials in your application and your wife's remarks should point out that she is relying upon your evidence.  You are (hopefully) submitting originals.

You need to read the guidance! Here's what it says...

> If you are applying as a family/group you do not need to provide
>   multiple copies of the same documents.

If they think you haven't read the guidance (which you have *NOT*), the application will be scrutinized more carefully (that's a bad thing).

**I have an old passport which is expired. Is there any need to send this passport as well with my application?**

What evidential value does your old passport have?  It's not required and if you do send it you should explain why you are submitting it and why you want them to look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have already printed our applications without writing GWF number of each other's applications in remarks section. Is there anything I can do to help in correlating my application and my wife's application?

Comment: Use an ink pen!

Comment: **treat both applications at 'arms length'** this is not right, if you are husband and wife, then you can send just one return shipping courier, specially if one of the spouse is financially dependent on the other.

Comment: **old passport which is expired. Is there any need to send this passport as well with my application** If you have current visa on your expired passport, then you MUST send both passports. Its always helpful to send expired passports so that consulate officer can view your last 10 year history of travels. This is something very important for UK visa.

Answer (score 2):

After receiving stamped passport ,I can safely outline the steps that I followed :-

1.) There is no need to send visa application papers separately. You can have them in the same envelope without any partition. Just have them sorted and don't mix them up.

2.) You need to send all passports - even expired passports.

3.)If you buy priority service, then receipts need to be on top of application papers. Also , on outside of envelope , mention "Priority service" in large letters.

4.) Do not use Fedex to send or return post.

Comment: Risky, it deviates from their mail room procedures and hence jeopardizes application integrity.  Please see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47975/recourse-for-bad-inaccurate-information-given-on-the-home-office-help-line  But it's great this worked out for you (using the NYC consulate presumably)