# UK visa courier question

Tags: visas, uk

Me and my husband are planning for UK visitor visa later in year and have our biometrics appointment for this Thursday at Atlanta Georgia. If anyone can explain the courier part of it we would appreciate it. 
Do we send the documents to UK embassy in Atlanta or which address? 
Does anyone recommend buying the round trip or one way courier option from VFS vs UPS? Thanks a bunch in advance.
Would we need to purchase 2 separate mailing labels or can we use one for both applications?

Answer (score 2):

This is answered in section 3 of the [UKVI guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa):

> Your biometric confirmation receipt will be stamped at your appointment. You then have 5 days to post this, your application form, your passport and supporting documents to UK Visas and Immigration (UKVI). All applications must be accompanied by a valid passport with at least one page without any endorsements. If the application arrives at the decision making centre without a passport the application will be refused.
>
> You should post your application to:
>
> Non-settlement applications
>
> UK Visas and Immigration
>   British Consulate General
>   845 Third Avenue
>   New York
>   10022
>
> ...
>
> **3.1 Return shipping**
>
> To have your documents returned you must provide a fully addressed prepaid electronic shipping label (we cannot accept ground services and non-electronic waybills). Put your return shipping label and envelope inside the package, and keep a copy of the waybill for your records.

See the answer to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/65240/uk-standard-visitor-visa-how-to-mail-multiple-applications-when-applying-as-a-f) on how the applications should be mailed.