# Fly to visit partner in UK with time in between refusals?

Tags: visa-refusals, borders

I'm a US Citizen in a relationship with a UK Citizen. 
Here is a break down of my timeline.

- Oct 2016 Visited the UK to be with my partner
- Nov 2016 Was refused at the border for a one way ticket and business cards in my wallet (border thought I was seeking employment) That was a stupid mistake of mine to purchase a one way ticket - lesson learned.
- Dec 2016 Tried once more and was let in and able to visit and be with my partner
- Came home and applied for visitors visa in Feb 2017. Was refused

I was wondering would I be able to try to visit in May 2017 (providing all of my supporting documents; financial stability, letter from employer, my partners contact information, Statement from my partner, and a roundtrip ticket?)

The last time I was able to visit was back in December. I was hoping since it will have been about 5-6 months in between from then until May? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, does it mean you are not going the route suggested here http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89170/how-do-i-find-an-immigration-lawyer-solicitor-to-help-with-my-uk-visa-applicatio

Comment: This sounds like a recipe for another refusal at the port of entry. Really, if you're serious about this relationship, don't waste any more money on plane tickets you won't be able to use, and have a UK immigration adviser help you.

Comment: You can try anything. One metric used to evaluate your application is [Frequent or successive visits – how to assess if an applicant is making the UK their main home or place of work](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/581550/Visitors-v5_0.pdf). It would appear to my untrained eye that with 4 visit/applications in four months you are a prime candidate for being refused for falling afoul of that metric.

Comment: Hey Gayot Fow! I've been speaking to a solicitor however I just wanted to see what responses were to this above question. I do not want to get another refusal so I'm just wanting to ask about future travels without a visa in my case since there will be a significant time in between a future visit. I have decided to go the Fiance visa route, but then was just a what if question. Pure curiousities sake.