# Re-entering the UK after ban is over

Tags: visa-refusals

I came to the UK in 2010. I studied there until 2012. The college suspended my visa in June 2012. The police caught me in September 2012. I stayed in the detention centre until December 2012. I came back to my country voluntarily with the Assisted Voluntary Return (AVR) scheme in December 2012.

Given that I overstayed nearly 90 days in the UK and left voluntarily with AVR, will I be eligible to get a visa again to the UK after 5 years to be a student in a top university in London? What would be the possibility to get a visa?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you need a lawyer not random strangers on the Internet. Some ideas for lawyers can be found in this [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/89179/4188).

Comment: Can only give opinion here. There's no answer possible. I'd say: At a top university? If you've top top people vouching for you? It is not impossible you might be allowed to visit. Otherwise as a proven illegal immigrant who the government had to pay to deport...not happening.