# UK marriage visitor visa

Tags: uk

I'm from Sri Lanka. When I was in the UK, I had a 10-year ban on my HSMP visa. After that I claimed asylum, and in 2016 I came back home voluntarily. My girlfriend is in the UK now. She has a refugee visa. Can I apply for a marriage visitor visa now?

Comment: When did your 10 year ban start? Can you meet the eligibility requirements and provide the mandatory documents? https://www.gov.uk/marriage-visa/eligibility

Comment: No, a Marriage Visitor visa is for those who do not intend to live in the UK after marriage, and your girlfriend is already there. A 10-year ban suggests a serious violation of your visa (Tier 1?) and while a ban in effect, applying for other types of visas will not lift the ban. You've left out important details: was asylum denied, were you under an administrative removal order when you left?

Comment: Mr Giorgio , I came back to country voluntarily, my band was start from 2010, my girl friend can't to come to srilanka, bcoz of her life threatening?? Is that any possible

Answer (score 2):

A Marriage Visitor visa is for those who do not intend to live in the UK after marriage. The more appropriate category would be a fiancé visa, although your girlfriend would have to be a settled person (not subject to immigration control) for this to be a consideration. It's not clear whether she has that status.

More importantly, your 10-year ban is the obstacle and, while it is in effect, applying for any other type of visas will not lift the ban, or reduce the time period.

You could consult a solicitor through the [Immigration Law Practitioner's Association (ILPA)](http://www.ilpa.org.uk/) as well as this [previous question on finding a UK immigration lawyer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89170/how-do-i-find-an-immigration-lawyer-solicitor-to-help-with-my-uk-visa-applicatio).