# My sister's UK visitor visa was refused

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

> REASONS FOR REFUSAL NRA v 1.0
>
> You have applied for a visa to visit the UK. In deciding whether you meet the requirements of [Appendix V: of the Immigration Rules for visitors](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitorrules), I have considered:
>
>  your application
>    your immigration history
>
> The decision
>
> I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am not satisfied that you meet the requirements of paragraph(s) V4.2 (a)(b)(c)(e) of Appendix V because:
>   - You applied for a visa to visit your sister in the UK for 21 days. The documents that you provided do not demonstrate that you are related to your sponsor. 
>   - You provided a supporting letter from your father however as there is no birth certificate I am not satisfied that you are related. 
>   - I note that you are a child student and therefore you do not have your own income, however it is necessary for me to see your overall situation in Ghana. The documents that you provided do not demonstrate your personal circumstances in the home country.
>
> In the view of the above I am therefore not satisfied that you intend to visit for a purpose that is permitted by the visitor routes and period as stated by you or that you will leave the UK at the end of your proposed visit. I am not satisfied that you will be adequately maintained and accommodated or will be able to meet the cost of your return or onward journey.

Comment: Awura Cynthia, This is the first time I am seeing V4.2 b in addition to the standard a+c+e. I believe the suspicion is you will end up absconding in UK because they have close relatives there. Please provide your immigration history, if you have been refused before etc for us to make an insightful decision.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking but I suspect there are a number of significant hurdles to be overcome, particularly as she is a *child student* and that she *(b) will not live in the UK for extended periods through frequent or successive visits, or make the UK their main home.* The latter implies an unfavorable UK immigration record and it would be unwise for her to make any further application without consulting an [***authorised UK solicitor***](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89170/how-do-i-find-an-immigration-lawyer-solicitor-to-help-with-my-uk-visa-applicatio)