# After being deported by the UK, is there any chance of getting a visa?

Tags: visas, uk, deportation

I have a friend; he’s been living in the UK since he was 18. He has applied for family and work visas but the UK has refused all of them. He got married to someone in the UK. Immigration didn’t think it was real and he got deported. He ended up coming back. Now he has met a girl and they are trying to do his papers again. He went back to his country and is applying there but will the visa get approved since he has been deported?

Comment: Why should it be approved?

Comment: Was your friends actually deported or just removed?

Comment: He paid them money to get his own ticket and leave so I’m not sure if that’s still considered deportation

Answer (score 8):

If I've read your post correctly, your friend has been denied visas repeatedly, to the point where he was deported, and, it seems, he's been living in the UK illegally.

He has the worst possible immigration record and, I'd estimate, exactly zero chance of ever getting a visa.

He needs professional help from an expert in UK immigration, not comments from a bunch of strangers on the internet. This will will be expensive, and carries only limited chance of success.

Comment: He has gotten a lawyer and paid lots of money and i know his a stupid question but i just want to be sure because i know that if you get banned it’s a 5 to 10 year to gain entry again

Comment: If _your friend_ has even a halfway decent lawyer he should be taking that lawyer's advice. I don't understand what _you_ are hoping to achieve here. What is it you want to be sure of?

Comment: You don’t have to be so rude this is what a website is for to get someone’s opinion on it i just wanted some advice if they would approve it or not

Comment: I'm not being rude. If you read my answer again you'll find my opinion spelt out in the second paragraph.

Comment: @Azdutch this site is not a forum, but one which has a question and answer format. Asking opinions doesn't fit, so those kinds of questions are usually closed. CannonFodder is correct: with your friend's immigration record, there is little chance of being issued a visa. Indeed, after the deportation, a ban may already be in place. Make sure that his lawyer is in the UK and among those [solicitors allowed to offer immigration advice](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89170/) as it is regulated. If his situation is impossible, no reputable solicitor would take the case (or the money).