# Applying for UK Visa but refused US visa 8 years ago on another named passport

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I am applying for UK visa but I have been refused on US visa 8 years ago which was by my other name.

My name is very long so sometimes I use the short name and sometimes I use my full name. My first passport used my short name. I was refused a US visa. After a few years, I've gotten a new passport using my full name. My full name looks totally different from my short name. Hence, I am going to apply for UK visa now in my current full-named passport.

So I am worrying whether the UK embassy will find my US refused visa application details? if yes, what will they do? Will the fact that my previous passport used another name mean that it will be less likely that they'll find it?

Should I let them know that I've used another passport 8 years ago for a US visa? or don't say anything when I apply for the UK visa?

Comment: You have to list your previous passports and submit them along with your appplication. Besides, you have to state in the application whether you had a refusal before. Providing an explanation for the refusal and a hopefully stronger application is a better bet compaired to lying on your application and hoping they won't find out.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help. My previous passport was not machine readable, it was hand written, hence, If I state that I've been refused on us visa 8 years ago on another named passport then will it be negative impact on my uk visa application? I am applying for very strong visa, and my status is very strong too. What about If I does not mentioned about my previous passport or us visa denial?

Comment: Just state the truth. You should not base your answer on whether it will have negative impact or not. The truth is the truth.

Comment: Consequences of lying is a 10 year ban on applying for a UK visa.

Answer (score 6):

You must answer all questions on the [application form](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/752360/vaf1a-visitandshorttermstay-11-18.pdf) truthfully.  This includes the following two questions:

> 2.7 Please give details of any previous passports, covering the last 10 years, including where these passports are now
>
> 6.3 Have you ever been refused a visa for any country, including the UK? If 'yes', please provide full details.

If you are found to have lied on the application form, your application will be rejected or your visa cancelled. You may be banned from entering the UK for 10 years.

Comment: Thank you very much. Okey if I state that both named passport details then will it put negative impact on my visa? to clarify you that, I am applying for tier1 visa for 5 years 4 months.

Comment: Yes, the past denial will have a negative impact. But it will be less negative than being caught in a lie. A past refusal by a place like the US means they will look if the reasons for that refusal are still applicable or not. A new lie means an automatic ban.

Comment: Thank you so much. My US denial was for asset ties, the does not believe I will return in my home country as I haven't submitted my assets proof. But in that time I was not good knowledge about immigration and my profession was not that much high as I have now and at this moment I have very high position in my profession and my recognition are worldwide now through world's top organizations that's why I am applying for UK Tier 1 visa.

Comment: For  my two names I have long history in my life, and I was fostered by my grandmother and uncle and they used my another name and mentioned my another date of birth then my parents. After my grandmother passed away, I've been back to my parents and they used my full name and another date of birth two years back date, they all weren't educated and that's why it was happened. Hence, I get new passport in my official most paper based name. So will it be consider by UK home office If I describe it?

Comment: and another question is, as they asked for last 10 years, Do I need to state that If I apply after 10 years?

Comment: Also will it work if I notarize the documents? if yes than what can be notarized?

Comment: Did your date of birth also change in the new passport? That's bad.

Comment: @Layes If you are wealthy enough to apply for a Tier 1 visa, you should [get a lawyer to assist](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89170/how-do-i-find-an-immigration-lawyer-solicitor-to-help-with-my-uk-visa-applicatio).

Comment: Thank you soooo much all of you for your kind help on my fact. Yes my date of birth also changed on my new passport because my parents used my birth date 1979 but my grand parents used my birth date and other name with 1981, so I gotten first passport when I was with my grand parents, but after they passed away, I back to my parents and gotten new passport with my official full name which on my educational certificates. We are 3 brothers and 3 sisters, and my parents unluckily weren't get education opportunity at their times.

Comment: Before my new passport, I've posted on the forum and asked people's help to be ensure that whether it will be issues or not but all contributors said that, country to country share only those people's details who already traveled from those 5 country, they does not share visa applicant information.

Comment: @mkennedy It's unsual in developed countries but why would it be bad? There must be lots of people in less-developed countries whose date of birth is uncertain, and any data item that is uncertain is liable to change when more information becomes available.

Comment: @David Richerby absolutely right you said my heart talking. I know how I am feeling about my situation and it was not happened intentionally.