# UK Visit Visa, How do we prove self employment?

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

My husband is applying for a visitors visa for the UK. He is self employed, or employed under his mother, working in their farm in SA. He gets regular income through cash and through his bank account (his mother wires money in his acc)

How do we prove his self employment? His mother does not have a business or a company, its like when you hire someone to be your gardener kind of 'employment', but not as a once of, but long term.

They live in a very big farm that needs daily maintenance and he does all the work. Would this even be called self employment or just under the 'savings'?

Do we just need his mother's confirmation letter and bank statement? as well as his bank statement for showing income for 3 months? 6 months?

Thanks.

Comment: @Senyora The employment situation you’re describing is never going get get past ECO scrutiny - the ’cash’ economy just doesn’t stack up when it comes to U.K. visa applications. If it’s a working farm then you need to prove that (certified trading accounts, mother’s tax returns, farm bank accounts showing wages paid to him etc). A confirmation letter from his mother is not going to be sufficient IMHO

Comment: This is not about bank statements. I am asking regarding what kind of documents can he provide to prove his self employment under his circumstances. But thank you for the message.

Comment: @Senyora If he’s self-employed receiving income, he surely ought to be paying tax via some means. Submit his tax returns.

Comment: @Senyora I think the UK tax authorities would class him as employed so you need to follow that route. To see what self-employed means in the UK do a search for self employed IR35 and you will find much more.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. He does not really have papers to say that he is 'self employed' legally. He also does not pay tax since hes not 'legally' employed. The farm does not have a bank account, theres no certified trading accounts whatsover. I suppose one would just call this as getting an allowance from family?

Comment: @Senyora I’d agree the factual description of his situation seems to be ‘unemployed’ with ‘allowance from family’. But you’re in danger of being inconsistent with your previous applications, which isn’t a good place to be with two previous refusals https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/131768/uk-visitors-visa-for-south-african-bf-husband-refused-twice-what-are-the-chanc

Comment: Lol thank you for reading my previous post. I can also agree which is why I am feeling very very skeptical into starting his next application. Unless his circumstances has changed (if he gets a job). I am not sure how to recover from the previous refusals. A letter explaining the mistakes does not seem to be reliable.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen Thanks for giving me a reality check ✔ Apart from the negativity, I dont suppose you have any useful advice you can share to us in regards to, I dont know, perhaps recovering from previous refusals? He is not a dishonest person since he is unemployed-- pardon me from sounding contradicting to my post, but as I've stated above 'Would this even be called self employment or just under the 'savings'?' --- since I was unsure as to whether to categorize what he's doing as 'self employed' or just getting 'allowance from family'.

Comment: @Senyora The truth is not always pleasant. You can call that negativity, that’s your prerogative. You can always claim he’s unemployed and being sponsored by his mother which is actually true. Chances of getting a visa with that are also slim to none. The only useful advice is tell him to get a job that is documented and pays taxes etc. Then this wouldn’t be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

He will not be approved for a visa with such a profile. Why would UK issue a visa to a law breaker?

The UK in evaluating a visa application is not only looking for evidence that the applicant will leave after the visit. They also care about issues like money laundering, tax and financial crimes.

Now if you’re saying he’s unemployed and sponsored by his mother that’s a different case. However he cannot claim to be employed with illegal (ie non tax paying non recorded) provenance of income.

Comment: @Senyora I know this is not what you want to hear but your husband is not going to get a visa and you’re wasting your money (and possibly risking a ban for deception, or frivolous applications or similar) if you reapply. He needs a) ties to his home country (job, dependents, property); b) a verifiable income source; c) proof he can afford the trip. He has none of those things, unfortunately. Even his mother’s sponsorship wouldn’t be enough because she can’t prove her income and this the source of his money if the farm has no bank account or trading accounts.

Comment: Thanks Traveller. I am well aware of those requirements. I guess we're just going to have to wait and improve his current circumstances before re-applying again. I do not feel like risking a ban.