# Will replacing a fake visa with a different fake visa cause me problems when applying for a legal study permit?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, applications, fraud

I have a problem, 4 years ago my passport was stamped with a fake visa. I want to apply for a legal study permit now so my mother sought counsel from this immigration services agents and she took my passport as they said they could remove the fake permit. They removed it but left a huge glue print on the page. The agent then stamped a fake Nigerian permit to cover the stain. Will the immigration officials or consulates verify this permit if I submit my application?

Comment: Wow a double minus makes a plus in real life as well? To hide one fake thing they added another fake thing?

Comment: Just to emphasize, any "agent" who thinks they can solve a problem by putting fake permits in your passport is an agent you want to run the hell away from as quickly as possible. You can see numerous past questions here where people have wrecked their immigration record, sometimes for life, by letting unscrupulous agents commit fraud on their behalf in the mistaken belief it would get them a visa. You are far better off applying yourself than using an agent who commits fraud and gets you blacklisted.

Comment: Ask for a new passport, then get a valid visa.

Comment: Was the first fake visa stamped / glued in with your knowledge and consent, or can you feasibly deny any prior knowledge that you are paying agent for fake? If there is no proof you knew they'll put a fake in your passport, you should report them to the police in the first place.

Comment: @Mołot As I said under another answer, in certain countries it's a very bad idea to report organized crime to government, since the government officials may be actively protecting it for bribes.

Comment: These are always fun to read

Comment: What could go wrong...?

Comment: To answer your question, we have to know if you used this passport, attempted to use or attempted to use it and were caught

Comment: The glue residue in itself should not have been a problem. A fake visa to cover it up definitely is.

Answer (score 134):

1. Lose your passport and get a new one without all this fake permit nonsense. (Edit: more precisely, wash it nice and hot as this answer https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/146620/4188 suggests.)
2. Lose everyone between you and relevant authorities, well meaning but clueless family members and also less well meaning agents (also known as scammers, conmen, whatever you want to call these criminals).

If you need a visa, bring a clean passport to the relevant authorities. It's that simple.

Some choice quotes from various agencies:

Australia, [Office of the Migration Agents Registration Authority](https://www.mara.gov.au/using-an-agent/using-a-registered-migration-agent/getting-help-with-your-visa-application/)

> Do I have to use a migration agent?
>
> No. You do not have to use a migration agent to lodge a visa application with the Department. The Department's website has information about types of visas and how to work out the right one for you. The website also has information on what is required for your visa application and how to complete and lodge the forms. Some forms are available in languages other than English.

Canada. [Do I need a representative to help me apply?](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=444&top=7)

> No. The Government of Canada treats everyone equally, whether they use a representative or not.
>
> All the forms and information that you need to apply for an Electronic Travel Authorization (eTA), visa and/or to immigrate to Canada are available for free on this website. If you follow the instructions in the application guide, you can complete the application form and submit it on your own.
>
> If you decide to use an immigration representative, be careful whom you ask for advice.

(Personally, I have completed my immigration to Canada without consulting a lawyer. I could, indeed fill out the forms.)

Can't find the relevant quote for the UK but we have a great [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/89179/4188) about [how do I find an immigration lawyer/solicitor to help with my UK Visa application](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/89170/4188) which states

> Let's say as a working figure 98% of applicants do not need a practitioner. The whole system is designed for normal people who can fill out the form and submit their stuff. It's simple and universally accessible.

Comment: From personal experience, I have had family members visit me in the UK a couple times a year over the last 15 years - every single time they completed the paperwork by themselves, without the need for an agent. That included a case where there was a previous overstay (exceptional circumstances were accepted and visa was granted).

Comment: At least in some countries, you can just apply for a new passport. The old one is badly damaged and worn out will be an acceptable reason (and even true in this case). I suggest to get as close as possible to the truth as soon as possible.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point!

Comment: I would say that people who come from certain cultures, like those where deception , bribes, etc. are normal ways of doing business with government, or those with high refusal rates... should get a competent agent who can teach them how to use honesty effectively.   Regarding your quotes from the immigration services, they really mean self-application works great *for the immigration service*... I.e. They are able to cheerfully and efficiently refuse people who just don't know how to apply.

Comment: And it is exactly in those cultures where the chances of finding a genuine agent vs a fraud is very very small...

Comment: Isn't it illegal to destroy your own passport, at least in some countries?  I'm pretty sure in the U.S. at least, a passport is government property, not personal property.

Comment: IANAL but based on this, destroying your passport *is* illegal in the U.S.:  "Alteration  or  mutilation  of  a  passport  issued  pursuant  to  this  application  is  punishable  by  fine  and/or  imprisonment  under  the provisions of 18 U.S.C. 154" (see: https://eforms.state.gov/Forms/ds11.pdf).  So this answer doesn't seem like good advice to me, at least not in general.

Comment: The passport is already mutilated, it doesn't get much worse than that... it might be skirting the rules but he needs a new passport and then what should he do with the old one .

Comment: @chx Good question; it seems like it's time for a lawyer. The exact best course of action would be country-specific of course, but it seems like OP needs to talk to someone who 1) knows the law, and 2) will protect OP's confidentiality while OP tries to determine the best way to proceed.

Comment: Unfortunately, i have been researching about this and i am now very much aware of this. What i needed was responses from other people to convince my Mother. She is a bit naive and this agent is scamming her. When i speak up, she says i am rebellious. And she insists these people have the best interests . I even screenshot all the responses just to convince her and she is UNMOVED. Apparently i know nothing and besides she is paying for it.. i respect my Mom but i wanted her to see what i was trying to tell her with reference to what other people know and their expertise on these isssues

Comment: Immediately stop applying for anything until you can pay yourself. The governments will NOT care whether it's your mom paying it will be YOUR immigration history and reputation that will get tarnished, possibly unrepairably so. She can't force you to apply.

Comment: @Chario The problem is that the immigration authorities consider you responsible for everything on your application. There's no "oh an agent did that" with a consulate; it's your application and your signature. If you're caught committing fraud, the agent walks away with your mom's money, but you're the one who gets a ban that will follow you for ages. If you're refused a visa for an ordinary reason, that's not a big deal at all, and you can apply again in the future after you have a stronger case. If you're refused a visa because you committed fraud, you've doomed your chances.

Comment: One has to look also what happens on the ground. I know first hand same statements by (the european countries government) 'direct application to the embassy is possible, no visa center needed'. Unfortunately the embassy in reality seems never to have free appointments (which is required)... the visa agencies have enough appointments though. I do not know if the situation in negeria is the same, but the official statement might not always align with the situation on the ground.

Answer (score 26):

Other visa officials might check your travel history for a new visa, and if they detect the forgery then it will be very difficult to get a visa. Visa officials will hold **you** responsible for what that agent did in your name.

**You** lied with that first fake.

Why should they believe that **you** are telling the truth now?

The best option for you is to get a new passport. That means the travel history in the old passport cannot be documented any more, which is bad, but it is better than a fake.

Answer (score 22):

Put the passport in the pocket of a shirt you don't like, and put that shirt in the washing machine.  Wash it nice and hot.

Result: the passport is damaged but still extant.  Send in the remains and apply for a replacement passport on the grounds of being damaged.

This way nobody can accuse you of the fraud where the passport is 'lost' but in fact something else happened to it (sold on the black market, etc).  You have evidence to prove your turn of events, and nobody is able to inspect your mind at the point of washing it (maybe you forgot to check your pockets, happens all the time...)

Answer (score 9):

Was that fake visa ever used? One hopes not, because if it was detected it is on the record and will cause future difficulties.

The best advice I can offer is to apply for a new clean passport ASAP directly from the issuing authority in your country. Tell the passport issuing authority your current one was accidentally destroyed. Apply for your study permit after receiving your new passport and shred or burn the current one.

Comment: The thing I'm struggling with is many of the answers are recommending what amounts to an illegal (in the U.S. at least) action to cover up another illegal action: "Alteration  or  mutilation  of  a  passport  issued  pursuant  to  this  application  is  punishable  by  fine  and/or  imprisonment  under  the provisions of 18 U.S.C. 154" (see: https://eforms.state.gov/Forms/ds11.pdf)

Comment: @bob Where do you see that?  Every answer I see recommends getting rid of the altered passport ASAP and starting from scratch.

Comment: The issue is in at least some countries getting a new passport normally involves sending in the old one. So does one send in the old passport (and in the process send their government evidence of the visa fakery) or do they claim the old passport was lost/destroyed so they can get a new passport without sending it in.

Comment: @PeterGreen, I can't speak for the original poster but in those circumstances I would be claiming it was destroyed accidentally. It might be a lie, but then again it might be a white lie if it fell into the fire. A lot would depend on whether there were visas or other information still current. In that case I would at least attempt to remove evidence of the remaining glue with a solvent. I have no idea which countries would consider that action as illegal.

Comment: @PeterGreen YMMV, but it's highly unlikely the contents of the old passport would be inspected, all they care about is that the passport itself is legit (which it is) and that the info on the photo page matches you (which it will).

Comment: I wouldn't mind applying for a new passport, but my problem is convincing my Mom the agents she is seeking council from and paying are scammers . And i am failing. I have only two dàys to convince her and all my efforts are in vain

Comment: And just to add to this, if in the specific case in question "losing" the old passport is illegal (and it seems to be in at least one country, the U.S., and could be in others), then it amounts to covering up a crime with a crime, which has moral and ethical and often (IANAL) legal ramifications.  Hence (that last part) why I think it may be time to talk to a lawyer or a good situation-dependent equivalent.  In the U.S. at least it seems like crime + cover up crime = harsher punishment (often).

Comment: @bob it seems that instead of talking to a lawyer, you want them to talk to a priest.

Comment: I was referring to the legal aspects when talking about a lawyer.