# About a re-entry ban

Tags: visas, uk, overstaying

I have been to the United Kingdom on a student visa when I went back to Nigeria after my studies.

However, I returned on a visit visa which I was granted. but I overstayed the visa due to certain issues and I was given a 1 year re-entry ban by the Home office.
At that time I was given an admission to do my doctorate degree.

Will I be granted a student visa if I apply for a PHD course and also pay the full tuition fee after the 1 year re-entry ban?

Comment: You are still in that one year ban, currently?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately no one will be able to tell you whether your application will be granted or not. Overstaying can cause refusals, even after the entry ban has expired. You may want to consult with a **UK based** immigration solicitor. If you do that [this answer has some excellent advice for choosing one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/89179/28009)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no-one can tell you whether your new visa will be approved. If you obeyed the re-entry ban, and are honest in your application there is a chance you will be accepted but you won't know for sure.

As mentioned in the comments, a UK based immigration solicitor can be found in this answer [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89170/how-do-i-find-an-immigration-lawyer-solicitor-to-help-with-my-uk-visa-applicatio/89179#89179).

Comment: The 1year re-entry ban is over and i am thinking of putting in an application for my phd.. I was given a 1 year re-entry ban because i overstayed in the country with 33days which i was taken to the detention camp  and also i paid for my ticket back to my home country my self. Will i be given a student visa

Comment: @Panzy02 It's hard to say, all you can do is try

Comment: Nobody can say for sure, but having overstayed once before is a serious problem. The OP has already established that they are the kind of person who overstays their visa. The OP will have to convince the authorities that they have changed their ways and will not do so again.