# Visitor Visa Refusal (false representation as did not declare alternative name, dual nationality with a T4 visa)

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, dual-nationality, student-visas

My son is 12 years old, he was born in Canada. He is holding a Valid T4 Visa and BRP card. But recently I applied a Chinese passport for him with an alternative name and alternative birthday.

I used his Chinese Passport to apply for UK Visitor Visa recently which was refused. On the application, I did not declare his Canadian passport information as China is not allowed Dual citizenship. Also, on his Chinese passport, his birthplace is China (the only way I can apply for his Chinese citizen was to declare he was born in China).[image]

Refusal reason and letter please kindly refer to attachment. [image]

Due to COVID-19, China revoked all Foreigner's visa to enter China, that's why I want to use a Chinese passport to let my son freely leave and return to China(all my family in China).
I am deeply worried that next time when he arrives at Heathrow Airport, the Border Control offer will not let him entering UK with his Canadian Passport and BRP card. Moreover, I am worried about his next T4 Visa renewal (July 2021) will be refused. Is there anything I can do to avoid that?

Comment: Ouch. You're up for a world of hurt, because in addition to not providing the information to the UK authorities and their noticing the discrepancy, you actually have a fake passport in your hands (or a real passport with false data). If you are worried about the UK, you should probably be even more worried about the PRC if they find out.

Comment: For future reference, lying to government officials can create so many problems that, even with any ethical consideration, it is not a useful strategy. In addition to the UK problem, there is risk in your son traveling to China if the PRC officials find out his passport application included a false date and place of birth. That is a long term problem. COVID related travel restrictions are relatively short term.

Comment: @amy I have rolled back your edits twice because the revisions you are making are simply removing important context. If you want to get good answers you should include all the relevant details.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass i want to delete my post. Tks.

Comment: DON'T go anywhere near China with that Chinese passport. Given the capricious nature of the Chinese government the consequences could be dire indeed if they find out what you've done.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass that's why I want to delete my post because of pRc.

Comment: You should not delete your post. But maybe you should make sure they can't find out who posted it - which they probably can't anyway, there is no identifying information here and there are lots of people called "Amy".

Comment: When you posted your question you committed to leaving it online. (And even when you could delete it here it would stay online, as some sites take the content to archive it.) Your best bet is to follow the information in this link (which you have to do yourself.) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa/96746#96746 That will remove your name from the post and the post from your account.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Get a lawyer, **get a lawyer NOW** - you should indeed be worried about your son's next entry to the UK, not just the renewal in 2021 (which stands a high chance of being refused). You are going to need a lawyer experienced in both UK and Canadian immigration issues to sort this one out, this is far beyond what we deal with here.

To sum up from the comments some of the issues you need legal assistance with:

- Fraudulently obtaining a Chinese passport with false details
- Deception during an application for a British Standard Visitor Visa

Holding a fraudulently obtained foreign passport may in-fact be illegal in Canada as well (I have an [open Law question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/55463/is-it-illegal-in-any-western-jurisdiction-to-hold-a-fraudulently-obtained-but-le/55492#55492) on this, so will update when I get a good answer), so theres potentially some issues there.

Comment: @AMY unfortunately, recommendations are as beyond us - we used to have a good community member who could point you in the right direction, but he hasn't posted in a while.  You can find suitable solicitors here https://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/

Comment: OP, take a look at [How do I find an immigration lawyer/solicitor to help with my UK Visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89170/how-do-i-find-an-immigration-lawyer-solicitor-to-help-with-my-uk-visa-applicatio).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112035/discussion-on-answer-by-moo-visitor-visa-refusal-false-representation-as-did-no).