# Can I ask the UK Home Office to explain their decision to give me a 10 year ban for deception?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-bans

First I’d like to say thank you to all of you that are willing to spend your time helping others that feel helpless when dealing with immigration authorities. I, for one, am extremely grateful for having this opportunity.

Now for my situation, I have spent hours and hours on here and haven’t seen a question pertaining to the 180 days per 12 month period “rule” that I was refused entry for violating.

Here are the details of what happened:

I visited England from March 2 2018 until September 11 2020 through 6 month visit visas because I had really close friends that are very well off financially and had invited me to vacation with them at their home and also travel with them to various places

Never overstayed 6 months
I honestly did not know about the 180 days per 12 months rule

Refused entry on September 14 2020 after being detained at Heathrow the reason given was for spending too much time in UK verses my home in California

While detained at Heathrow, I Was given my interview at 3am that night after a long flight and completely devastated from the refusal and told I was being refused entry  at 4am. Not allowed to get my personal belongings. Sent home the next day at 2:45pm

Upon entry I told the officer I was there to visit my friends, which was the truth, but I did not think to tell them I had been on several dates with someone in England at that time and they never asked anything about that in the 50 plus questions they asked during my interview in the middle of the night

I applied for a  marriage visit visa October 21 2020 because he and I became very close in the months following my refusal and decided to get married and settle in California but Trump imposed a ban from U.K. so he couldn’t fly to me to get married. My application was refused on the grounds that I used deception because I did not tell them I had been dating Someone on September 14th.

The letter states that because I used deception and lied that future applications would likely be refused for up to 10 years. And I have no right for appeal or administrative review

I would like to point out a few things that do not make sense to me at this point.

- Why was I able to enter England so many times for such a long time with no warning I was breaking a rule? I told the officer at Heathrow if only the UK.gov website said visit visa are for 6 months and ONLY 6 months this would not have happened. I know it is my responsibility to know the rules but it would be so much clearer if it was written this way.
- Prior to flying to California on September 11 2020 I received an email from the Home Office stating a Covid extension was granted and that they would send a follow up email in the beginning of August with further guidance. They never sent such email. I emailed them on August 26th asking for guidance because Covid was rampant in my home town and I was terrified to go home at that time and was very safe where I was but my extension was up on August 31st. I had seen information about applying for an exceptional indemnity so I applied for it but only got a confirmation email that they received it and nothing further until 2 months later when they said my application was not needed because I had another application pending, I assume My marriage visit visa,Then in November  I received another email stating that they apologize for the delay in processing my application for the indemnity and asked me to send them information so they could process it. They also should have told me that it was ok to stay in England until I received their decision and none of this would have ever happened
- How can God like power be given to these people where they can devastate people’s lives with no questions asked?
- And finally, I looked up using deception when applying for a visa on the UK.gov website and it clearly says using deception is not being truthful on any of the questions on the application or submitting false documents but nowhere did it say anything about occurrences with border force at entry points but they used information from that in my refusal letter.

My question is Other than spending a lot of money on an attorney, how can I get them to explain their decision and justify the 10 year ban they imposed when I did not ever lie to them?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135754/discussion-on-question-by-julie-is-there-any-way-i-can-personally-ask-for-the-ho).

Answer (score 16):

> Is there any way I can personally ask for the home office (UK) to explain their decision to give me a 10 year ban for deception?

Don't do that. Don't try to do that. Don't even think about doing that.

I feel for you:  I understand that you are frustrated and feel treated unfairly, but it's best to leave your emotions out of it and get professional help. Sorry, but you already have made a lot of mistakes, and chances are you will make more if you try to tackle this on your own.

Your best shot to get this straightened out [is to have a competent lawyer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89170/how-do-i-find-an-immigration-lawyer-solicitor-to-help-with-my-uk-visa-applicatio). Any further interaction with the Home Office should be carefully scrutinized and planned BEFORE it happens.