# Is it advisable to visit the UK now that I am married to a British citizen?

Tags: uk, visa-free-entry

I am a citizen of St. Kitts and Nevis. I married my British citizen husband in October 2019 in my country. We are planning on applying for the spousal visa to the UK after he has met the financial requirements. Since he has only recently started working in a new job, we expect this process to take at least 9-12 months.

My husband would like me to visit him in the UK, seeing as we otherwise have a very lengthy separation ahead of us before we can live together. I desperately want to see him too, but I am concerned that I run a very real risk of being denied entry at the UK border. I am currently not employed and having a UK citizen spouse might lead the border officer to believe I intend to overstay. I have visited the UK a handful of times (visa free for about 3-4 weeks per visit) while we were dating, always disclosed that I was visiting my boyfriend and never had much of a problem, but I was also enrolled in a graduate program during those times so could show some tie outside the UK.

My husband believes I am being overly paranoid, but I have built up a very good travel history over the years and would hate to have a denied entry ruin that. I know I am right to be cautious, but am I being overly so? What advise would you give if we do decide to have me visit?

Comment: You should read [this detailed answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/99734/12065) by the much-missed Gayot Fow, who clarifies that not only is a **short** visit to a spouse who is in the process of qualifying for a spousal visa usually a valid premiss for entry, but it can in fact be an immigration "brownie point", as it is evidence of *intervening devotion*.