# UK Visitor Visa for Girlfriend

Tags: visas, standard-visitor-visas, tourist-visas

Is it a good idea to state future intentions, be upright honest?
stating along the lines of...

She plans to visit and then return to Vietnam.
We do intend to marry on the next visit (on a separate visa or in her country) to then be eligible for a spouse visa.

All in the correct and legal way, showing we understand the importance of her return and not returning will ultimately jeopardise our future chances....?

Thank you so much!

Comment: No, it’s completely unnecessary IMHO. The best way to demonstrate intention to leave the UK at the end of a visit is to show a *compelling* reason(s) to do so, such as a job, family dependents etc

Comment: One step further would be to say it would be highly _unlikely_ your girlfriend will be granted a visitor visa _because_ she would be viewed as likely to remain/unlikely to leave, _because_ she is your girlfriend. Sad to say, but true and evidenced with other questions here in the past.

Answer (score 5):

**Do tell the truth, but don't give more information than is necessary.**

So in the application she should call you her boyfriend. Trying to pretend you are not risks getting a ban for deception. Tell the truth about your actual plans.

However don't talk about possible plans that you might have on the visa application. Plans can change. Concentrate instead on showing that she satisfies what the immigration officers are interested in - that she has the means to support herself in the UK without working, and that she will return to her home country.

She may be asked about marriage plans at the border, in which case it's good to indicate that you haven't definitely decided to marry, but you are aware that you are not allowed to on the current visa and will get the right one if you decide to marry.

Comment: The late, great Gayot Fow used to use the phrase "*maintain the relationship*", which very neatly summed up the immigration-acceptable purpose of these vists; more can be read eg [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/99734/12065).