# I am an EU citizen. My husband isn't. Can he travel to the UK without a visa?

Tags: uk, norway, eu-citizens, spouses, colombian-citizens

I am a Lithuanian citizen, my husband is from Colombia and we both live in Norway. He has a residence permit to live in Norway. Written on it is that he is the spouse of [my name]. We want to travel to the UK and on the next day fly to Colombia. Does he need a visa to enter the UK?

Comment: Maybe not - only the embassy can give you a more definite answer. Here is some text from the EU - https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm

Comment: @DetlevCM That's not true. British consulates will generally not answer visa questions. And this question can certainly be answered definitively by people on this site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to find out if I need a transit visa for a layover in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk)

Comment: Per the question I've linked, as the holder of a "common format residence permit", your husband will be eligible for transit without visa.

Comment: @MJeffryes It would be the job of the embassy to tell you if you need a visa or not - unless they don't want people to visit, but then they might as well close the visa service.

Comment: @DetlevCM No it isn’t. UK embassies will not give any visa information, other than maybe giving you a UK Visas & Immigration web address. Furthermore, you won’t get any personalised information from UKVI. You are expected to interpret their web pages yourself.

Comment: @DetlevCM furthermore, some countries' embassies have given incorrect visa advice and gotten people onto trouble as a result.  This can happen for example because embassies are generally part of the foreign ministry while immigration services are part of the interior ministry, and communication between the two is sometimes less than ideal.

Comment: @phoog That may be another problem, but one that can be rectified (with improved internal processes). Expecting people to interpret anything (as MJeffryes implies) can simply described as not fit for purpose.

Comment: @DetlevCM the problem is that "improved internal processes" do not exist.  Specifically, for the UK, regardless of what services you think its consulates and embassies *should* provide, they do not provide advice about visas.  The government [does not even accept liability for incorrect advice given over its (very expensive) phone assistance lines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/47975/19400).  Trying to get such advice from an embassy or consulate is sure to fail.  The only sensible solution is to learn the rules for oneself or find (somehow) reputable independent legal advice.

Comment: @phoog Maybe the UK should sort out the mess it calls "administration". Then again, the Home Office is not the only part of the UK government that doesn't exactly work as expected... - While one can expect that people try to read information provided by the government in an effort to ascertain the answer, the only people who can provide definite clarification are members of the administration.

Comment: @DetlevCM of course the UK should sort out its mess. But they haven't, nor have they shown much desire or capacity to do so.  This leaves potential travelers more or less on their own.

Comment: @phoog Or one does the sensible thing and avoids travelling there (same for any other country) unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @DetlevCM I doubt that most people using this site are of the opinion that travel should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @phoog If countries are trying to be actively hostile or at least unfriendly to people who want to visit?

Answer (score 3):

> Does he need a visa to enter the UK?

Probably not. It depends on whether your husband's card says 'Residence card of a family member of a Union citizen,' or the equivalent in another language, which it probably does, or if it otherwise indicates that it is issued under article 10 or article 20 of the free movement directive.  In this case, he qualifies to [enter as the holder of an Article 10 card](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card), without a visa, if he travels with you (as the question indicates is your plan):

> If you are a non-EEA national who holds a valid genuine residence card, issued to you as the family member of an EEA national who is exercising free movement rights in another EEA State (i.e. not your EEA relative’s Member State of nationality) under Article 10 of Directive 2004/38/EC (the ‘Free Movement Directive’), you may use this document for travel to the UK if you are accompanying your EEA national relative here, or joining your EEA national relative in the UK.

Answer (score -2):

According to this website https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y your spouse will need a visa

Comment: In addition to being short on analysis, this answer reaches the wrong conclusion.