# Translating Lease Contract for UK Visa

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, translations

I want to apply to visit my wife in UK. I am Jordanian with a Hungarian residence permit, and I want to submit my Lease Contract for my UK visitor Visa. The contract is written with two languages, Hungarian and English, but there is a little part of it that contains landlord's name and his mother's name and contact details are not translated in English. Do I need to translate it or is it fine like that?

Comment: For a definitive answer rather than one based on opinion or experience (which may differ from your specific situation) you should consider contacting UKVI for advice, as mentioned on https://www.gov.uk/world/organisations/british-embassy-budapest/office/british-embassy#visa-services

Comment: @Traveller UKVI's advice via phone or email is pretty useless (and you have to pay for it). Their policy is that they can only repeat information found on their website (see [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47975/recourse-for-bad-inaccurate-information-given-on-the-home-office-help-line/48488#48488)). I would suggest contacting the visa application centre instead of UKVI.

Answer (score 1):

If it's literally just names and address/phone number/email that is "not in English" then I would not worry about "translating" them. Names and addresses are not "in" a language.